# eagle library model for STM32F730R8T6

Tags: pcb-design, footprint

I'm designing small DSP device, currently I've been using stm32 development board but now I need to move to dedicated PCB. I can make footprint for uC myself, but I believe it should be available somewhere and  I'm just looking wrongly.

Comment: I found it by googling "eagle library model for STM32F730R8T6" (your title). It was first hit.

Comment: Sorry, but questions seeking off-site resources like libraries, code, etc are off topic in most of the SE system including here.  Your choices are typically to search and find something, then decide if it meets your need, to adapt something you find, or to make something from scratch that is exactly what you want.  There is often a lot of similarity between different STM32 parts so making a custom derivative of something existing can be a possibility.

Comment: You can download that footprint from Mouser's website.